# How to kill all instances of a program running apart from the newest one

Tags: debian, ssh, process, kill

I have a problem whereby my script keeps spawning new ssh processes. This shouldn't happen I know, but I would like to clean the old ones up from time to time.

If I do :

`ps -ef | grep "ssh" | awk '{print $2}'`

I get a list of all the PIDs of the ssh processes running.

I would like to kill all of them, apart from the last one or two that has been spawned (The processes with the highest PID numbers).

How would I go about this?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
while [ $(pgrep -c ssh) -gt 1 ]
do
  pkill --oldest -f ssh
done
```

As long as there's more than one `ssh` process, kill the oldest ("least recently started") one(s). Least-recently-started might be a better metric than "lowest PID" in case your PID space wrapped around or you used randomized PIDs.

Comment: You could be more specific with the pgrep and pkills, if needed -- to match a longer process name & arg string, or to match only your user (`-u engineer999`), etc.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. A bit off-topic, but is it dangerous to have all of these ssh processes spawning all the time? I'm using just a Rasberry Pi. I guess only the latest process will be active, but then, there is probably a limit to the number of processes I can have

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what the processes are doing. Computers compute, so if the process is doing something you expect, that's one thing. If it's getting in your way, it might be worth a new question, detailing out what it's doing and what's going wrong with it.